# Looper in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, dom, android-asynctask

I'm learning about HTML and parsing data with XML DOM. For this, I've created an App that reads the Wheater from Yahoo's wheater API.

When executing the app, shows an error in the logcat that says: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not caller Looper.prepare().

I don't know what this means, or if the code is right.

This is the link to the XML file of Yahoo's wheater API:

http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=766273&u=c

And this is my code:

```
public class WeatherActivity extends Activity {

private static final String WEATHER_URL = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=";
private static final String MADRID_CODE = "766273";

private static final String LOCATION_NAME = "location";
private static final String CITY_NAME = "city";
private static final String CONDITION_NAME = "condition";
private static final String TEMPERATURE_NAME = "temperature";
private static final String FORECAST_NAME = "forecast";
private static final String DAY_NAME = "day";
private static final String HIGH_TEMPERATURE_NAME = "high_temperature";
private static final String LOW_TEMPERATURE_NAME = "low_temperature";

private static final String TODAY = "Today";
private static final String TOMORROW = "Tomorrow";

private Button mButton;
private TextView mCity;
private TextView mToday;
private TextView mTomorrow;


private class WeatherInfo {
    String city;
    int temperatureNow;
    int lowTemperature;
    int highTemperature;
    int lowTemperatureTomorrow;
    int highTemperatureTomorrow;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mCity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.city);
    mToday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.today);
    mTomorrow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tomorrow);

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            launch();
        }
    });
}

private void launch(){
    try {
        new WeatherAsyncTask().execute(MADRID_CODE);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(WeatherActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


private class WeatherAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, WeatherInfo>{

    @Override
    protected WeatherInfo doInBackground(String... params) {
        String code = params[0];
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(code))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Code cannot be empty");

        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(WEATHER_URL + code);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            WeatherInfo info = readWeatherInfo(is);
            return info;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(WeatherActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(WeatherInfo result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        showResult(result);
    }



    private WeatherInfo readWeatherInfo(InputStream is){
        if (is == null)
            return null;

        WeatherInfo info = new WeatherInfo();

        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = builder.parse(is);
            Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("item");

            for (int i=0; i<items.getLength(); i++) {
                Node item = items.item(i);
                NodeList datos = item.getChildNodes();

                for (int j=0; j<datos.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node dato = datos.item(j);
                    String etiqueta = dato.getNodeName();

                    if (etiqueta.equals(LOCATION_NAME)) {
                        String texto = obtenerTexto(dato);
                        if (texto.equals(TEMPERATURE_NAME)) {
                            info.city = texto;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (etiqueta.equals(CONDITION_NAME)) {
                        String texto = obtenerTexto(dato);
                        if (texto.equals(CITY_NAME)) {
                            info.temperatureNow = Integer.parseInt(texto);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (etiqueta.equals(FORECAST_NAME)) {
                        String texto = obtenerTexto(dato);
                        String day = null;
                        int high = -111;
                        int low = -111;

                        if (texto.equals(DAY_NAME)){
                            day = texto;
                        } else if (texto.equals(HIGH_TEMPERATURE_NAME)){
                            high = Integer.parseInt(texto);
                        }  else if (texto.equals(LOW_TEMPERATURE_NAME)){
                            low = Integer.parseInt(texto);
                        }

                        if (day.equals(TODAY)){
                            info.highTemperature = high;
                            info.lowTemperature = low;
                        } else if (day.equals(TOMORROW)){
                            info.highTemperatureTomorrow = high;
                            info.lowTemperatureTomorrow = low;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

        return info;
    }


    private String obtenerTexto(Node dato) {
        StringBuilder texto = new StringBuilder();
        NodeList fragmentos = dato.getChildNodes();

        for (int k=0;k<fragmentos.getLength();k++) {
            texto.append(fragmentos.item(k).getNodeValue());
        }
        return texto.toString();
    }

}

private void showResult(WeatherInfo info){
    mCity.setText("Temperature in " + info.city);
    mToday.setText("Today: " + info.temperatureNow + " F (min: " + info.lowTemperature + " F / max: " + info.highTemperature + " F).");
    mTomorrow.setText("Tomorrow: min: " + info.lowTemperatureTomorrow + " F / max: " + info.highTemperatureTomorrow + " F.");
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot show a `Toast` in the `doInBackground` of an `ASyncTask`

Try wrapping it in a `runOnUIThread()` like:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(WeatherActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: or you can use `onProgressUpdate()` preimplemented method of `AsyncTask`. With this, you can pass `e.getMessage()` to `publishProgress()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use preimplemented method `onProgressUpdate()` of `AsyncTask` which allows you to post Toasts. To do this, you have to change your `AsyncTask` declaration into

`private class WeatherAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, WeatherInfo>`

and add method

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    Toast.makeText(WeatherActivity.this, values[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and inside your `AsyncTask` you can catch your exception and do this

```
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    publishProgress(e.getMessage());
}
```

All this is available by default in `AsyncTask` without the need of creating new runnables.